# How can I decrypt a encrypted binary file in azure storage?

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted blob file using PowerShell? Couldn't find any method to do it? If anyone has a solution please let me know.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details. As written, we don't know anything about how your file is encrypted (you haven't shared any code), we don't know anything about its destination (e.g. are you decrypting to memory? to a local file? to another blob?). We don't know what you've tried so far, where you're stuck, errors, etc... These are the details you should include in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use C# code and execute the code using a Powershell script if you really want to do that.

Follow the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault#decrypt-blob-and-download)

```
// In this case, we will not pass a key and only pass the resolver because
// this policy will only be used for downloading / decrypting.
BlobEncryptionPolicy policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(null, cloudResolver);
BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions() { EncryptionPolicy = policy };

using (var np = File.Open(@"C:\data\MyFileDecrypted.txt", FileMode.Create))
    blob.DownloadToStream(np, null, options, null);
```

Comment: Not sure how you can post an answer to a question with no code and no details. We don't even know anything about how such a file was encrypted. We don't know where the decrypted file is supposed to go. We don't know why PowerShell is involved (and your answer ignores PowerShell completely). Best not to answer such a vague question, and instead get clarification from the OP.